# Strange sound from Laptop, Microphone, Speakers or Soundcard?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, microphone

I have recently purchased a second hand computer. There didn't seem to be anything wrong with it on purchasing, however recently I have noticed a small issue.

Any time I play sound or listen through my headphones, I can hear what seems to be the CPU working (ie when beginning a new task, there is a small crackling). Also if I tap my laptop I can hear the sound louder, as if it is being picked up by the mic and then playing that sound in real time through the speakers or headphones.

I have tried reading other topics but cannot find an answer to this question.

These are the specs I am running on;

Windows 7 Home Premium 32bit
Pentium Dual Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10Ghz 2.10Ghz

I hope someone can help me with this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a built in microphone?

Answer (score 0):

It may happen your hard drive is kind of old and produces noise somehow, due to low RAM bottle-necking your hard drive or any other cause (which can be because it simply is old, or faulty).

Seen some reviews on the web and i would try using "SeaTools".
This software which is free can diagnose common problems in hard drives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will give it a go, but as I said its not just the hard drive making noises. This is deffinately some sort of recording device issue as any noise that occurs outside the laptop as I said such as tapping the casing near the mic, is then played through the speakers. Imagine the sound of patting a microphone, but thats happening when I type not using the mic.

Comment: if you have an internal mic wich is close enough to a component making the sound it would just seem the sound is caused by the audio hardware, that is the case scenario i was refering to.

Comment: I ran all available tests, it seems that there is nothing wrong with the hard drive (which is a relief).

Comment: eliminating hard drive problems the only thing I can recall of is indeed audio hardware problems, since aamof there are not any other movable parts inside your laptop (excluding fans or an in-drive cd-rom/dvd).

Comment: I do have a built in microphone :)

Comment: try disabling that mic on sound settings to see if the weird sounds go away please

Answer (score 0):

Open your audio manager, click microphone tab, and set play back volume to zero. I hope it can solve your problem.